# initiate random play without clicking mouse

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am writing a code that plays a game by selecting values randomly when the mouse is clicked.

```
def random_play(event):
    #some random selections
    fig.canvas.draw()


cid = fig.canvas.mpl_connect('button_press_event',random_play)
```

How to play the game as soon as I run the code without the need to click the mouse?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just execute the code within the event handler for mouse clicks before you start listening for clicks.

Essentially just make it pick a random selection and draw it then start listening for clicks.

Comment: Thanks Foster. However, I am not sure if I have understood clearly.

Comment: Let's say that on click you want it to do a random selection and then  fig.canvas.draw(), if you want it to happen once without you clicking, just execute those commands at the start of the script.